# Is using custom table to suit business needs instead of transients a big hit to page load speed?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, database, cache, transient

I am working on changing the caching strategy to save the response of an API(which refreshes data in every 30 minutes). Among other things, I came across transients and their unreliable nature of getting expired at any time.

Instead of transients, I want to save API call data in a custom table and keep the table updated using some background process. And, for my shortcode rendering, I will do a DB call to fetch 10 values from this custom table. Is there any big speed concern in fetching data from the custom table instead of using transients in the page rendering?

Comment: How much data are we talking?

Comment: The data in the table will vary from customer to customer of my plugin. It might vary from 1 to 10k entries in the custom table with each entry storing the API response corresponding to that. Similarly, A single post might need 1,2 or even 100 values from this table on page rendering depending how many entries a customer wants to use

Comment: Yeah you want a custom table for that. Transients would be inappropriate.

Comment: But would there be any speed difference due to DB read? If yes, I can think of another approach to club 10 entries from the custom table in one transient(it's like another storage above custom table) and save only those which are frequently used. The only reason I didn't pick this first is the overhead to implement same in my design and another is transient's unreliable nature of getting expired at any time.

Comment: Well yeah, every query's gonna have *some* impact, but it'll probably be negligible. I think you're overstating the unreliability of Transients. If the transient expires your code should just get a fresh copy. What's the problem?

Comment: @learning_13 is the problem that you want transients that never expire? Have you considered making the API request via the client, or storing the data in user meta if it's user specific?